# Aggregation across multiple databases in MongoDB or solution to sync collections across databases

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

We have a requirement in our project to write aggregation queries across multiple mongodb databases. I see that it is not possible with Mongo to query another database in an aggregate query. What would my options be in this case?

We would not mind to create the same collections manually across multiple databases as long as these derived collections sync automatically when the primary collection is updated. Does Mongo have any such solutions to keep collections across databases in sync?

Answer (score 1):

"Almost."  You can use the Change Stream feature to listen for changes on the source database but you must write a piece of code to insert/update the material into the target database.